# Prove that Wallis' product and Euler's formula directly imply that $(-1/2)!=\sqrt{\pi}$

Tags: limits, factorial, pi, infinite-product

(This occured to me recently,
and I was pretty sure that
it was true,
so I was pleased that
it really was.
This has almost certainly
been published
many times before,
but I didn't see it
in either of the Wikipedia articles
on the Wallis product
and Euler's limit formula
for factorial
so I thought that
I would propose it here.)

Euler's formula for general factorial is

$$z!
=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!n^z}{\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^n (z+k)}
. $$

Wallis' product is

$$\frac{\pi}{2}
=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{4k^2}{4k^2-1}
$$

Prove that
Wallis' product and
Euler's formula
directly imply that
$(-1/2)!
=\sqrt{\pi}
$.

I'll post my answer
in a few days
if no one else does.

Comment: For information on asking question here see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/

Comment: I edited your $\rm\LaTeX$ just a touch. I hope you don't mind!

Comment: Quick question for a hint: how long is your proof? I have an idea of how to proceed, but it feels too easy.

Comment: No problem. My stuff usually needs editing, but one of my mottos is "Good enough is good enough".

Comment: @Cameron Williams: My solution, in my usual excruciating detail, is about 20 lines.

Comment: Euler's invention of the Gamma function in the first place was explicitly in relation to the Wallis product, specifically his observation that a certain product form for $n!$ was equivalent to the Wallis product when $n=1/2$. (For details, see the first few pages of [this article](https://maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/leonhard-eulers-integral-an-historical-profile-of-the-gamma-function) which gives the history of the Gamma function.)

Comment: For the primary source, see [here](https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/euler-works/19/) for a translation of the relevant paper by Euler.

Comment: I answered a similar problem [earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4837824/1-2-from-the-infinite-product-definition-of-gamma/4837889#4837889), although you would need to convert your limit into the multiplicative formula for the gamma function which shouldn’t be too difficult.

Comment: Well, I guess Euler beat me to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Rewrite the limit as an infinite product**
$$
\begin{align}
z!
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!n^z}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^n(z+k)}\tag{1a}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!(n+1)^z}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^n(z+k)}\tag{1b}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)^z\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{z+k}\tag{1c}\\[6pt]
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{z+k}\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^z\tag{1d}\\[6pt]
&=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k}{z+k}\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^z\tag{1e}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a):}$ Euler's Formula
$\text{(1b):}$ $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}n=1$
$\text{(1c):}$ $n!=\prod\limits_{k=1}^nk$
$\text{(1d):}$ $n+1=\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{k+1}k$
$\text{(1e):}$ definition of an infinite product

According to $(3)$ in [this paper](https://maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/leonhard-eulers-integral-an-historical-profile-of-the-gamma-function), $\text{(1b)}$ is Euler's Formula.

$\text{(1e)}$ is also proven in $(4)$ of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4822202).

---

**Evaluate $\boldsymbol{\left(-\frac12\right)!}$**
$$
\begin{align}
\left(-\frac12\right)!
&=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k}{-\frac12+k}\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^{-\frac12}\tag{2a}\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k}{-\frac12+k}\sqrt{\frac{k}{k+1}}\tag{2b}\\
&=\prod_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k+1}{\frac12+k}\sqrt{\frac{k+1}{k+2}}\tag{2c}\\
&=\sqrt2\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k}{\frac12+k}\frac{k+1}k\sqrt{\frac{k+1}{k+2}}\tag{2d}\\
&=\left(\sqrt2\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^2}{k^2-\frac14}\frac{k+1}k\sqrt{\frac k{k+2}}\right)^{1/2}\tag{2e}\\
&=\left(2\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^2}{k^2-\frac14}\right)^{1/2}\tag{2f}\\[9pt]
&=\sqrt\pi\tag{2g}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a):}$ plug $z=-\frac12$ into $\text{(1e)}$
$\text{(2b):}$ apply exponent of $-\frac12$
$\text{(2c):}$ substitute $k=k+1$
$\text{(2d):}$ pull out the $k=0$ term
$\text{(2e):}$ take the geometric mean of $\text{(2b)}$ and $\text{(2d)}$
$\text{(2f):}$ $\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k+1}k\sqrt{\frac k{k+2}}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(n+1)\sqrt{\frac2{(n+1)(n+2)}}=\sqrt2$
$\text{(2g):}$ Wallis' Product

Answer (score 5):

Here is my answer.

There is my usual
excruciating detail
since, as always,
I wrote nothing down on paper
but directly entered this
into MacDown,
my MathJax editor of choice.

Euler's formula for general factorial is

$z!
=\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n!n^z}{\prod_{k=1}^n (z+k)}
$.

Wallis' product is

$\dfrac{\pi}{2}
=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{4k^2}{4k^2-1}
$

I first tried to put
Wallis' formula
into a form
that I hoped could match with
Euler's formula
for $(-1/2)!$.

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{\pi}{2}
&=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{4k^2}{4k^2-1}\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{2k}{2k-1}\dfrac{2k}{2k+1}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{2k}{2k-1}\dfrac{2k}{2k+1}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{2k}{2k-1}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{2k}{2k+1}\\
\end{array}
$

I then plugged $-1/2$
into Euler's formula,
manipulated it a bit,
squared that,
split and regrouped terms,
did some index fiddling,
and, shazam, it matched!

$\begin{array}\\
-\dfrac12!
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n!n^{-1/2}}{\prod_{k=1}^n (-1/2+k)}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n!n^{-1/2}2^n}{\prod_{k=1}^n (-1+2k)}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^n (2k)n^{-1/2}}{\prod_{k=1}^n (-1+2k)}\\
\text{so}\\
(-\dfrac12!)^2
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^n (2k)^2}{n\prod_{k=1}^n (-1+2k)^2}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^n (2k)}{n\prod_{k=1}^n (-1+2k)} \dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^n (2k)}{\prod_{k=1}^n (-1+2k)}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac1{n}\prod_{k=1}^n\dfrac{ (2k)}{(2k-1)} \prod_{k=1}^n\dfrac{ (2k)}{(2k-1)}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac1{n}\prod_{k=1}^n\dfrac{ (2k)}{(2k-1)} 2\prod_{k=2}^n\dfrac{ (2k)}{(2k-1)}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{2}{n}\prod_{k=1}^n\dfrac{ (2k)}{(2k-1)} \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{ (2(k+1))}{2k+1}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{2}{n}\prod_{k=1}^n\dfrac{ (2k)}{(2k-1)} \dfrac{ \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(2(k+1))}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(2k+1)}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{2(2n+1)}{n}\prod_{k=1}^n\dfrac{ (2k)}{(2k-1)} \dfrac{ \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(2(k+1))}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}(2k+1)}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{2(2n+1)}{n}\prod_{k=1}^n\dfrac{ (2k)}{(2k-1)} \dfrac{ \prod_{k=2}^{n}(2k)}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}(2k+1)}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{(2n+1)}{n}\prod_{k=1}^n\dfrac{ (2k)}{(2k-1)} \dfrac{ \prod_{k=1}^{n}(2k)}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}(2k+1)}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{(2n+1)}{n}\prod_{k=1}^n\dfrac{ (2k)}{(2k-1)}  \prod_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{(2k)}{(2k+1)}\\
&=2(\dfrac{\pi}{2})\\
&=\pi\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: This is much simpler. The length is deceptive and mostly due to the excruciating detail you mention in answer.